# Look for specific file and execute stored procedure

Tags: python, file-watcher

One of my processes is writing data into text file and then a sql stored procedure stages that data in one of the sql table.
As of now I am not sure about the timing of the file, so I need a **file watcher** that will look for that file and when that file will be available it will **stage that data into sql table**.

I have tried the below piece of code but I am not able to stop and execute sql stored procedure when I get that file. For ex: filename is `Process1_Timestamp.txt`.

I have created the below process:

1. Created function to return files in a directory.
2. Created a function to compare two list.

And then this:

```
def fileWatcher(my_dir: str, pollTime: int):
    while True:
        if 'SeeFiles' not in locals(): #Check if this is the first time the function has run
            previousFileList = fileInDirectory(watchDirectory)
            watching = 1
            print('First attempt')
            print(previousFileList)
        
        time.sleep(pollTime)
        
        newFileList = fileInDirectory(watchDirectory)
        
        fileDiff = listComparison(previousFileList, newFileList)
        
        previousFileList = newFileList
        if len(fileDiff) == 0: continue
        doThingsWithNewFiles(fileDiff)
```

How I can stop looking when I get that file and trigger the next sql process?

Comment: When you find the file use [break](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement) to exit the while loop.

Comment: Unrelated to stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at Watchdog https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/

Largely taken from the example on https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html#a-simple-example and using FileSystemEventHandler https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#watchdog.events.FileSystemEventHandler

```
import sys
import time

from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer


class CustomHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        print(f'File or directory name: {event.src_path}')
        # do stuff


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.' # use the current directory if one is not supplied as the first argument but you could provide the path in any way you like.
    event_handler = CustomHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

In a more minimal form:

```
import time
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer


class CustomHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        print(f'File or directory name: {event.src_path}')
        # do stuff


if __name__ == "__main__":
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(CustomHandler(), '/path/to/my/directory', recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

FileSystemEventHandler has other methods apart from `on_created()` you can override if you don't just want your code called when a file or directory is created.

If you are not interested in directories that have changed you can use event parameters e.g.

```
class CustomHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        print(f'Created file or directory name: {event.src_path}')
        # do stuff
    
    def on_modified(self, event):
        if not event.is_directory:
            print(f'Modified file name: {event.src_path}')
            # do other stuff
```

If you want to stop after finding the first file:

```
import time
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer


class CustomHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        if not event.is_directory:
            print(f'File name: {event.src_path}')
            # do stuff
            observer.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(CustomHandler(), '.', recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while observer.should_keep_running():
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Make sure you read and understand https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/installation.html#supported-platforms-and-caveats these caveats may apply to all solutions, not just Watchdog.

Answer (score 1):

Think it's as simple as this... If I'm reading your code right.

```
def fileWatcher(my_dir: str, pollTime: int):
    while True:
        if 'SeeFiles' not in locals(): #Check if this is the first time the function has run
            previousFileList = fileInDirectory(watchDirectory)
            watching = 1
            print('First attempt')
            print(previousFileList)
    
        time.sleep(pollTime)
    
        newFileList = fileInDirectory(watchDirectory)
    
        fileDiff = listComparison(previousFileList, newFileList)
    
        previousFileList = newFileList
        if len(fileDiff) == 0: continue
        break
    doThingsWithNewFiles(fileDiff)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).